# YouTube LiveBroadcast remove bound stream and transition lifeCycleStatus from "ready" to "live" or "created"

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have an issue with trying to transition a YouTube LiveBroadcast from `ready` to `live`. The `liveBroadcast` looks like this

```
  {
   "kind": "youtube#liveBroadcast",
   "id": "VALID_ID",
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2018-03-12T13:11:52.000Z",
    "channelId": "CHANNEL_ID",
    "title": "Test",
    "description": "Live stream",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "URL",
      "width": 120,
      "height": 90
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "URL",
      "width": 320,
      "height": 180
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "URL",
      "width": 480,
      "height": 360
     },
     "standard": {
      "url": "URL",
      "width": 640,
      "height": 480
     }
    },
    "scheduledStartTime": "2018-03-12T13:26:23.000Z",
    "isDefaultBroadcast": false,
    "liveChatId": "LIVE_CHAT_ID"
   },
   "status": {
    "lifeCycleStatus": "ready",
    "privacyStatus": "private",
    "recordingStatus": "notRecording"
   },
   "contentDetails": {
    "boundStreamId": "BOUND_STREAM_ID",
    "boundStreamLastUpdateTimeMs": "2018-03-12T13:26:19.065Z",
    "monitorStream": {
     "enableMonitorStream": false
    },
    "enableEmbed": false,
    "enableDvr": true,
    "enableContentEncryption": false,
    "startWithSlate": false,
    "recordFromStart": true,
    "enableClosedCaptions": false,
    "closedCaptionsType": "closedCaptionsDisabled",
    "enableLowLatency": true,
    "latencyPreference": "low",
    "projection": "rectangular",
    "enableAutoStart": false
   }
```

I have replaced some private details with constants (but they are all valid).

I want to transition from ready to live which seems simple enough. Unfortunately I receive an error invalidTransition

```
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "youtube.liveBroadcast",
    "message" : "Invalid transition",
    "reason" : "invalidTransition",
    "extendedHelp" : "https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/transition#params"
  } ],
  "message" : "Invalid transition"
}
```

This seems very odd and every time I encounter it I wonder why I cannot go from `ready` to `live`. At the same time I wonder why I cannot go back to the status `created` and remove a boundBroadcast.

Anyone know any way to transition to `live` from this state?